# Symfony2 FOSUserbundle add user to group

Tags: symfony

i'm using FOSUserBundle Groups.

Now i want to add the groups to my user (when adding a new)

I tried to load the groups to my form but failed.

Here the form:

```
$builder
        ->add('enabled','checkbox',array(
                'required'  => false))
        ->add('locked','checkbox',array(
                'required'  => false))
        ->add('username','text',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('email','email',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('password','password',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                    'choices'  => array('ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin', 'ROLE_USER' => 'Benutzer'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'multiple' => true
                ))
        ->add('groups', 'choice',array(
            'choices'   => $this->getGroups(),
            'multiple'  => true 
        ))
        ->add('save','submit')
        ;

}
```

Also i tried

```
$builder
        ->add('enabled','checkbox',array(
                'required'  => false))
        ->add('locked','checkbox',array(
                'required'  => false))
        ->add('username','text',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('email','email',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('password','password',array(
                'required'  => true))
        ->add('roles', 'choice', array(
                    'choices'  => array('ROLE_ADMIN' => 'Admin', 'ROLE_USER' => 'Benutzer'),
                    'required' => true,
                    'multiple' => true
                ))
        ->add('groups', 'collection', array(
                'type'  => 'choice',
        ))
        ->add('save','submit')
        ;
```

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 1):

I now get the output with:

```
->add('groups','entity',array(
                  'class'    => 'UniteUserBundle:usergroup' ,
                  'property' => 'name' ,
                  'multiple' => true ,
        ))
```

Not the next problem... it don't persist to my table 'fos_user_user_group' :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating a `GroupType` and instantiating that type in the collection?

```
    ->add('groups', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new Name\Space\To\GroupType(),
    ))
```

For example your `GroupType` might look like the following code. Notice it's mapped to the Group entity.

```
<?php

namespace Name\Space\To\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class GroupType extends AbstractType
{
    public $group;

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('group', 'hidden', array(
            'error_bubbling' => false,
            'required' => false,
        ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Name\Space\To\Entity\Group',
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'namespaceto_grouptype';
    }
}
```